# Replace character values conditionally by count

Tags: r

I have this kind of data:

```
df %>% str()
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Title: chr  " Mr" " Mrs" " Mr" " Mr" ...

df <- structure(list(Title = c(" Mr", " Mrs", " Mr", " Mr", " Mrs", 
                               " Mr", " Miss", " Mr", " Mrs", " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", " Mrs", " Mr", 
                               " Mrs", " Mrs", " Mr", " Mr", " Miss", " Mrs", " Mr", " Master", 
                               " Mrs", " Mr", " Mrs", " Mr", " Miss", " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", 
                               " Mr", " Mrs", " Mrs", " Mr", " Mr", " Miss", " Miss", " Mr", 
                               " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", " Mrs", " Mrs", " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", 
                               " Mrs", " Mrs")), .Names = "Title", row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

My goal is to replace those values with `""` if they occur less then 6 times.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% count(Title) %>%
arrange(-n)

Title   n
Mr      29          
Mrs     15          
Miss    5           
Master  1
```

In this case, this would be `Master` and `Miss`.

I tried it this way but it didn´t work:

```
df$Title[df$Title %in% c("Miss", "Master")] <- ""
```

I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  count(Title) %>%
  arrange(-n) %>% 
  mutate(Title=ifelse(n<=6, "", Title))
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#   Title      n
#   <chr>  <int>
# 1 " Mr"     29
# 2 " Mrs"    15
# 3 ""         5
# 4 ""         1
```

or regarding what your desired output is, you can add:

```
df %>% 
  count(Title) %>%
  arrange(-n) %>% 
  mutate(Title=ifelse(n<=6, "", Title),
         n=ifelse(n<=6, "", n))
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Title  n     
#   <chr>  <chr> 
# 1 " Mr"  29 
# 2 " Mrs" 15
# 3 ""     ""    
# 4 ""     ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider to use the trimws() function to remove the spaces

```
mylist <- structure(list(Title = c(" Mr", " Mrs", " Mr", " Mr", " Mrs", 
                     " Mr", " Miss", " Mr", " Mrs", " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", " 
                      Mrs", " Mr", 
                     " Mrs", " Mrs", " Mr", " Mr", " Miss", " Mrs", " Mr", " Master", 
                     " Mrs", " Mr", " Mrs", " Mr", " Miss", " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", 
                     " Mr", " Mrs", " Mrs", " Mr", " Mr", " Miss", " Miss", " Mr", 
                     " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", " Mrs", " Mrs", " Mr", " Mr", " Mr", 
                     " Mrs", " Mrs")), .Names = "Title", row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")

> df <- as.data.frame(mylist)
> table(nchar(df$Title))

 3  4  5  7 
29 15  5  1 
> df$Title <- trimws(df$Title)
> table(nchar(df$Title))

 2  3  4  6 
29 15  5  1 
> c(df$Title)
 [1] "Mr"     "Mrs"    "Mr"     "Mr"     "Mrs"    "Mr"     "Miss"   "Mr"     
"Mrs"    "Mr"     "Mr"    
[12] "Mr"     "Mrs"    "Mr"     "Mrs"    "Mrs"    "Mr"     "Mr"     "Miss"   
"Mrs"    "Mr"     "Master"
[23] "Mrs"    "Mr"     "Mrs"    "Mr"     "Miss"   "Mr"     "Mr"     "Mr"     
"Mr"     "Mr"     "Mrs"   
[34] "Mrs"    "Mr"     "Mr"     "Miss"   "Miss"   "Mr"     "Mr"     "Mr"     
"Mr"     "Mr"     "Mrs"   
[45] "Mrs"    "Mr"     "Mr"     "Mr"     "Mrs"    "Mrs"
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to replace `Master` and `Miss` in correct way. However your `data.frame` doesn't have `"Master"` and `"Miss"` but have `" Master"` and `" Miss"` instead. You have leading spaces in all your entries.